# cast “int32_t” to “static const int32_t”

Tags: c++, constants

(Major edit: The way I posed the original question was bit confusing. So, I am trying to improve the question)

I am trying to convert “int32_t” to “static const int32_t” type. However, I could not figure out how to use static_cast and const_cast together. Any help would be appreciated.

I want to do this so that rather than initializing my “static const int32_t IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2” to a hardcore value, I would like to set this based on value passed to the relevant function.

Say, the value of iNoOfSamples_In is 128, I would like to set IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2 to 128 too; but, as as a “static const int32_t” like this:

```
int32_t iNoOfSamples_In = 128;
static const int32_t IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2 = iNoOfSamples_In;
```

However, when I go to declare an array of size IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2

```
    double dTime_Scale[IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2]; // Line 80
```

I get the following errors (line 80 marked in code snippet):

```
SpecialPulses.cpp(80) : error C2057: expected constant expression
SpecialPulses.cpp(80) : error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
SpecialPulses.cpp(80) : error C2133: 'dTime_Scale' : unknown size
```

So, it seems that max_envelope_elements is not constant.

Comment: The error message is clear, you can't assign to a variable that is `const`.  A `const` variable cannot be assigned a new value, that why you declare a variable `const` in the first place.

Comment: Also, in the context of `myRFPulseArray[IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2]`, the value is no argument, but the size of the array of `sSample` which is created by this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the error message says, you can't declare a variable as `const` and then change its value. However, if you are trying to call a function that takes a `const int_32`, that's fine - just declare the variable as `int_32`. In that case, the `const` just says that the function doesn't change the value of the parameter inside the function, but even if it did it wouldn't affect your variable anyway.

Comment: sorry that my question was confusing. Please have a look at my improved question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By const it means that it's constant and by definition a constant is:

> *a situation or state of affairs that does not change.* - google"

so you cannot change the value of the const variable after you initiated it.

Please do note that const are used most of the time for code readability in replacement for magic numbers in code.

take this for example

```
if(a>b%2)
 //do something
```

What the heck is 2 and what does that do?

while if you actually can use something like this.

```
if(a>b%SOME_CONST_VALUE)
//do something
```

you can actually tell by the const variable what you are actually doing rather than having the programmer/developer who will maintain your code what the heck does that if statement does.

Comment: sorry that my question was confusing. Please have a look at my improved question. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
const_cast<int32_t>(IRF_MAX_ENVELOPE_ELEMENTS2)=256;
```

You can change your constant values like that, I hope this will help your problem.